# Pointer and Functions

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new in C programming. I've written this code from [RTKLIB](http://www.rtklib.com/) library.

```
extern void satno2id(int sat, char *id)
{
    int prn;

    switch (satsys(sat, &prn)) {
        case SYS_GPS: sprintf(id,"G%02d",prn-MINPRNGPS+1); return;
        case SYS_GLO: sprintf(id,"R%02d",prn-MINPRNGLO+1); return;
        case SYS_GAL: sprintf(id,"E%02d",prn-MINPRNGAL+1); return;
        case SYS_BDS: sprintf(id,"C%02d",prn-MINPRNBDS+1); return;
    }
    strcpy(id, "");
}
```

In this function first argument is Input and second is Output. Now the question is how I get the value of second argument in `main()` function?
I've written this block of code but it's getting error. What's wrong here?

```
int main(){
    char *id;
    satno2id(68, &id);
    printf("satellite number is %s", *id);
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are talking about?

Comment: `char *id;` is just a pointer, it has no space to store the value. Instead try `char id[42];` if an id can be 42 characters long.

Comment: Your C compiler gave you some diagnostic messages for this code. Did you just ignore them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, the name of an array degrades to a pointer to the first element of that array.

The `id` in the function expects a pointer to the first element of a character array (string). This is evident because `sprintf()` function, which is used to write to a character array is used in `satno2id()`.

So send an `char` array instead like

```
char id[4];
satno2id(68, id);
```

I made the size of the array to be 4 as `satno2()` seems to be writing a string of length 3. The extra byte is to store the `\0` terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an *array* to `satno2id`, not an uninitialized pointer. Also, to avoid buffer overflow you also need to pass the length of the array so the function can assert that the array is long enough.

```
#include <assert.h>

#define LEN(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0])

extern void satno2id(int sat, char id[], int idLen)
{
    int prn;

    assert(idLen >= 4 + 1);

    switch (satsys(sat, &prn)) {
    case SYS_GPS:
        sprintf(id, "G%02d", prn - MINPRNGPS + 1);
        break;
    case SYS_GLO:
        sprintf(id, "R%02d", prn - MINPRNGLO + 1);
        break;
    case SYS_GAL:
        sprintf(id, "E%02d", prn - MINPRNGAL + 1);
        break;
    case SYS_BDS:
        sprintf(id, "C%02d", prn - MINPRNBDS + 1);
        break;
    default:
        strcpy(id, "");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char id[8];

    satno2id(68, id, LEN(id));
    printf("satellite number is %s\n", id);
    return 0;
}
```